# Add Custom Button in User JavaScript for MediaWiki

Tags: javascript, php, mediawiki

**I want to create a button like the one that inserts your signature. How to do this?**

After doing some research I figured out that I can insert custom buttons with the `User:MYUSERNAME/common.js` page.

I saw several examples. But the wiki references and informations are often splittet across multiple pages and out dated. So I try here if I am lucky and find someone who tried similar things.

Who can help me with this:

```
var customizeToolbar = function() {
    $('#wpTextbox1').wikiEditor('addToToolbar', {
        section: 'advanced',
        group: 'format',
        tools: {
            "comment": {
                label: 'Comment',
                type: 'button',
                icon: '//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/37/Btn_toolbar_commentaire.png',
                action: {
                    type: 'encapsulate',
                    options: {
                        pre: "<!-- ",
                        post: " -->"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
};
```

When I do it like this, nothing happens because customizeTooblar most likely gets never called. When I remove it, it says that wikiEditor is not defined.

I already enabled `$wgAllowUserJs = true;` in LocalSettings.php.

I saw this question: [Creating custom edit buttons for MediaWiki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3079390/creating-custom-edit-buttons-for-mediawiki) Is this still the way we should do this kind of things? This is possibly not a dublicate question because I am already asking  about my particular issue here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the initiation code was missing.
This code should directly add a smiley label to your advanced toolbar:

```
var customizeToolbar = function() {
    /* Your code goes here */


$( '#wpTextbox1' ).wikiEditor( 'addToToolbar', {
    'section': 'advanced',
    'group': 'insert',
    'tools': {
        'SimpleComment': {
            label: 'Comment', 
            type: 'button',
            icon: '//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a4/Gnome-face-smile.svg/22px-Gnome-face-smile.svg.png',
            action: {
                type: 'encapsulate',
                options: {
                    pre: "preText", 
                                        post: "postText"
                }
            }
        }
    }
} );








};

/* Check if view is in edit mode and that the required modules are available. Then, customize the toolbar … */
if ( $.inArray( mw.config.get( 'wgAction' ), [ 'edit', 'submit' ] ) !== -1 ) {
    mw.loader.using( 'user.options', function () {
        // This can be the string "0" if the user disabled the preference ([[phab:T54542#555387]])
        if ( mw.user.options.get( 'usebetatoolbar' ) == 1 ) {
            $.when(
                mw.loader.using( 'ext.wikiEditor.toolbar' ), $.ready
            ).then( customizeToolbar );
        }
    } );
}
// Add the customizations to LiquidThreads' edit toolbar, if available
mw.hook( 'ext.lqt.textareaCreated' ).add( customizeToolbar );
```

Can be added to `wiki/User:YOUR_USRNAME/common.js`

In `LocalSettings.php` this option must be enabled    `$wgAllowUserJs = true;`